# Why is the thermal de Broglie wavelength the benchmark for determining the relevance of quantum effects at a given temperature?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, newtonian-mechanics

I am wondering because De Broglie equation only applies for a state of well defined momentum. Such a state is not a realistic wave function as it exists everywhere. Therefore, I am wondering why its wavelength will be the determining factor of whether there is quantum interference among particles. If these particles are modelled as pure momentum states then they interfere everywhere. So the question then is how does the de Broglie wavelength ensure that wavefunctions of particles can be considered well apart from each other so as not to interfere

Comment: Use a Gaussian wavepacket. This is a good caution that plane waves are pathological in some ways.

Comment: But what has the thermal De Broglie wavelength got to do with the gaussian wavepacket?

Comment: So instead of making a plane wave state with specified De Broglie wavelength, I'm telling you to write down two Gaussian wavepackets instead.  Namely two that are separated by an amount typical for the number density being considered and have the specified expected momenta. I'm leaving you to choose the parameters however you wish.

Comment: Thank you. I got it, just that the uncertainty of the gaussian at time t=zero was what was related to the thermal de broglie. But what happens at t >>0. Or is this the reason why they want separation >>> thermal de broglie so they can claim that for the period of time in consideration, the wave function has not spread out so as to interfere with each other

Comment: If you want, continue that problem to see how long it takes for the overlap to grow. Then do that for increasing separations. Also you mean $t>>t_0$ not $t >> 0$.